# how to align ion-tab icon to the right?

Tags: ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app that I use a couple of tabs as shown below:

```
<ion-tabs color="dark" [selectedIndex]="index" class="right-align">  
  <ion-tab [root]="homePage" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="aboutPage" tabBadge="{{itemCount}}" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="ios-cart" tabBadgeStyle="danger"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

By default these two tab icons are centered on the page, is it possible to align these tab icons to the right and reduce the gap between both the icons?

Answer (score 0):

There's an attribute for the `ion-tabs` tag to change the icon position:

```
<ion-tabs tabslayout="icon-end"> ... </ion-tabs>
```

The `icon-end` value will push your icons to the right.

About the gap you need to be more clear of what gap this is. Between the tab buttons there's only 4px of padding split by the two buttons, it's not a big gap, but you can add more padding to the icon so it can be pushed far to the right.

Hope this helps.